# How to pass Java session to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I'm trying to pass session from Java (myapp.java) to JavaScript (myapp_2.js). Below is my Java code:

```java
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
 @ResponseBody
 public Map<String, Object> getSessionAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
     attributes.put("userUsername", (String)session.getAttribute("userUsername"));
     attributes.put("accessGroup", (String)session.getAttribute("accessGroup"));
     attributes.put("username", (String)session.getAttribute("username"));
     LOG.info("username set to: " + (String)session.getAttribute("username"));
     LOG.info("accessGroup set to: " + (String)session.getAttribute("accessGroup"));
     LOG.info("userUsername set to: " + (String)session.getAttribute("userUsername"));
     return attributes;
 }

  @RequestMapping(value = {"doLogin"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
  public String doLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String pathConfig = String.valueOf(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME")) + "/conf/sfmonitor/credentials.xml";              
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      // System.out.println("my username: " + username);        
      String hashedPassword = md5(password); 
      // System.out.println("my password: " + hashedPassword);     
      try {
          File credentialsFile = new File(pathConfig);                
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = dBuilder.parse(credentialsFile);
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();                   
          NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
          for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
              Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
              if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                  String userUsername = eElement.getAttribute("username");
                  String userPassword = eElement.getAttribute("password");
                  String accessGroup = eElement.getAttribute("access_group");                                                             
                                 
                  if (username.equals(userUsername) && hashedPassword.equals(userPassword)) {                                    
                      session.setAttribute("isLoggedin", true);   
                      session.setAttribute("accessGroup", accessGroup);                     
                      session.setAttribute("userUsername", userUsername);    
                      session.setAttribute("username", username);               
                      session.setMaxInactiveInterval(21600);                                                        
                      return "redirect:/dashboard";                 
                  }
              }
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  
      return "redirect:/login";
  }
```

This is the session I need to pass to myapp_2.js:

```js
session.setAttribute("accessGroup", accessGroup);
                          System.out.println("accessGroup set to: " + accessGroup);
                          session.setAttribute("userUsername", userUsername);    
                          session.setAttribute("username", username);
```

This is myapp_2.js:

```js
function collectGroup(lstAgent) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/",
      data: {
        action: "getSessionAttributes",
      },
      success: function (data) {
        // console.log(data);
        var userUsername = data.userUsername;
        var accessGroup2 = data.accessGroup;
        var username = data.username;
        console.log("userUsername set to: " + userUsername);
        console.log("accessGroup set to: " + accessGroup2);
        console.log("username set to: " + username);
        // Call your function to collect group passing accessGroup, userUsername and username
        collectGroup(lstAgent, accessGroup2, userUsername, username);

        let ul = document.getElementById("dropdown-group");
        if (ul.childNodes.length <= 1) {
          let rawGroup = ["All"];
          var accessGroup = accessGroup2;
          let filteredAgents = lstAgent.filter(function (agent) {
            return agent.agent.group === accessGroup;
          });

          // get the group names from the filtered agents
          for (let i in filteredAgents) {
            rawGroup.push(filteredAgents[i].agent.group);
          }

          let fixGroup = rawGroup.filter(function (currValue, index, self) {
            return self.indexOf(currValue) === index;
          });
          insertGroupToDropdown(fixGroup);
          $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
            $(this)
              .parents(".btn-group")
              .find("div", ".btn", ".btn-default")
              .html($(this).text());
            filterCard();
          });
        }
      },
    });
  });
}

console.log(userUsername);
        console.log(accessGroup2);
        console.log(username);
```

Result from log:

```
userUsername set to: undefined
accessGroup set to: undefined
username set to: undefined
```

There's a value if I checked from LOG.info, but my JavaScript seemed unable to get the session (undefined). How can I solve it, or is there a simple way to pass the session from Java to JavaScript?